# How to remove multiple items from an array with the same id, but keep one while increasing its "qty"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an Array like so:

```
const arr = [
{ price: 12, desc: 'desc', id: 123, qty: 1 },
{ price: 12, desc: 'desc', id: 123, qty: 1 },
{ price: 12, desc: 'desc', id: 123, qty: 1 }
];
```

I want to be able to delete `x` amount of items until there is only one item left with the id of `123`. However I also want to increase that item's qty by however many other items there were with that same id.

So for example I want  a resulting array like so:

```
const result = [ { price: 12, desc: 'desc', id: 123, qty: 3 } ];
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please add your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce` to group and count the matched ids.

```js
const arr = [{ price: 12, desc: 'desc', id: 123, qty: 1 },{ price: 12, desc: 'desc', id: 123, qty: 1 },{ price: 12, desc: 'desc', id: 123, qty: 1 }];

// The function Object.values returns the values of every object, for example:
// accumulator = {
//    "123": { price: 12, desc: 'desc', id: 123, qty: 3 }
// }
// The function Object.values returns:
// { price: 12, desc: 'desc', id: 123, qty: 3 }
const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  // The accumulator 'a' will contain objects as follow:
  // {'123': {id: 123, desc: 'desc'...., qty: 2}}
  
  // This line checks for the current object with 'c.id'
  // If that object doesn't exist, a new object is created with
  // a further property called 'qty' and then we add +1
  (a[c.id] || (a[c.id] = Object.assign(c, {qty: 0}))).qty++;
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how reduce works with this? And what the content inside reduce is doing. I am a JS noob.

Comment: Thank you @Ele, I think that helps alot!